# If colE contains value then import colAY from same sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importrange

I am trying to import 2 columns from one sheet into another but trying to make sure I import only the cells from col2 when col1 has a value (all different values).

I imported my first column needed (column E) with the following formula `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("LINK", "ALL Product Overview!E3:E"), "select Col1 where Col1 is not Null", 0)`

Now I am trying to import my second col (column AY) but only the cells in Column AY when the same cell number in column E has value.

Comment: enclose you QUERY() within an =IF(not()) https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093305?hl=en

Comment: Use array with your columns in query
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("LINK", "ALL Product Overview!E3:E"), IMPORTRANGE("LINK", "ALL Product Overview!AY3:AY")}, "Select * where Col1 is not Null", 0)

Comment: @User24601 Would you give an example of how such a query would look? The reference to the documentation on `NOT` doesn't seem to provide much guidance.

Comment: @OlegS Perhaps your comment would be better submitted as an answer - for the benefit of future users.

Answer (score 1):

Use array with your columns in query

```
=QUERY(
 {IMPORTRANGE("LINK", "ALL Product Overview!E3:E"), 
  IMPORTRANGE("LINK", "ALL Product Overview!AY3:AY")}, 
"Select * where Col1 is not Null", 0)
```